# Linking two portals in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have built a mob grinder in Minecraft, 200 blocks into the air. Obviously, in a Survival World, getting up and down the can be difficult, and ugly.

I have attempted to use the "two portals - one teleport" idea; that is, build two Nether Portals in the same chunk, and you can use them to travel between two point is the Overworld. However, I cannot get this to work - I have had mixed results.

I have tried building the two portals 150 blocks away from each other (one at y=50, the other at y=200), light one, and enter the nether, to establish the link, then light the other one. This has given me mixed results. Either:

1. A third Nether Portal spawns in a separate location (as if the first portal was broken)
2. I only reappear out of the first Nether Portal, regardless of where I enter.

Is there a way to use two Nether Portals as a form of "Elevator"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, but you'll need to make the portals yourself

Firstly, break all the portals you have currently.

Secondly, in the overworld, make your first portal and note down the co-ordinates, but divide the X and Z axis by 8, leaving the Y axis the same.

Then, go to the nether in that portal, break the nether portal, and build another one at the noted down co-ordinates, if the portal is not already at that location in the nether.

Now, you can go back to the overworld. Build your second portal somewhere else, and note down the co-ordinates in the same way as I described earlier. Light it, then go back to the nether in your first portal.
*Do not enter this portal yet!*

Build another nether portal at the co-ordinates you just noted down, and if you did everything correctly, going through that portal should take you to the overworld.

[Further Reading](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_portal)

Comment: Hi, that's great to hear! Quick question though, will this work if one of the coordinates is less than 8? E.g., z=4? Should that just be z=1 then?

Comment: Well, Minecraft just looks for the closest portal, so of course that'd work.

Comment: It didn't work... I made one at `x=877 z=-5`. The corresponding portal in the Nether was `x=109 z=0`. I then made another portal at `x=897 z=-71`, the matching portal being `x=112 z=-8`. I followed the steps - went in through the first portal, built the corresponding portal in the nether at the coordinates. I went back to the overworld, which matched. I then built the second portal, lit it, then went back in through the first portal again, built the second corresponding portal, lit it, then went back through, only to reappear through the first portal.

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter which portal I enter through, I always reappear at the first.

Comment: @Ben That's very strange. Minecraft nether portals are weird. I'll test this more when in a couple hours. Should I delete my answer for now?

Comment: Not just yet. I believe this is correct, there's just a minor detail missing.

Comment: @Ben http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Nether_portals might be useful. This is very similar to how I explained in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55746/discussion-between-ben-and-okx).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I did quick test of this in 1.7.10 and it worked perfectly. Each block you move in the nether is equal to eight blocks in the overworld, so all you have to do is create a base portal, and place a portal directly above it where you need to go and I mean this it has to be exactly a duplicate like so:

[image]

Then you must create a portal (in the nether) 25 blocks above the portal that you transferred to. Then light it and hop in. It should take you to the above portal in the overworld. It does for me ;)

**EDIT**

When entering either portal in the overworld it will take you to the portal at the bottom in the nether, so instead of using the portal to get back just jump ontpo a slime or piece of water. If you ever enter the nether and try to exit it will always take you to the top nether portal.

Divide the height by 8 to get the amount of blocks you need to go to create the last enerportal in the nether.

Comment: Now, my only question is, how can I achieve this if the other portal is at Y=200? In survival, there's no way I can match those two Y coordinates...

Comment: Each block in the nether is equal to one block in the overworld including Y. So you divide 8 by 200 = you get 25 blocks above the original nether portal in the nether.

Comment: @Reflexive This is incorrect. Only X and Z are divided.

Comment: However, you could put your portal as high up as possible so that it's the closest one.